# Autowiring a TagAwareCache and injecting into service

Tags: symfony

I want to configure a TagAwareCache with APCU backend.
The result should be injected into a service.

So I have this config.yml:

```
cache:
    pools:
        data_evaluator_cache_items_cache: # apcu backend
            adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
            public: true

data_evaluator_cache:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter
    arguments:
        $itemsPool: "@data_evaluator_cache_items_cache"
    public: true

AppBundle\Service\DataEvaluator:
    alias: data_evaluator
    arguments:
        $cache: "@data_evaluator_cache"

data_evaluator:
    class: AppBundle\Service\DataEvaluator
    public: true
    arguments:
        $cache: "@data_evaluator_cache"
```

The service looks like this:

```
class DataEvaluator {
    public function __construct(Logger $l, AdapterInterface $cache) {
    }
}
```

From what I tested, the injected `$cache` is indeed a `TagAwareAdapter`, so that's fine.

However, I doubt that the item inner cache being given to the `TagAwareCache` is an apcu cache. The items are fine, these are my tags.

Here are two screenshots of the web tool bar. In the first, I see that `data_evaluator_cache_items_cache` is used for my cache items/payloads.
[image]

The next screenshot makes me nervous: `cache.app` is used for the tags!  And `cache.app` resolves to `FilesystemCache`.

[image]

BTW: Is it a good idea to use APCU for items and tags? I do not need distributed caching or so. I heard that modern PhpFilesCache is a good thing since PHP7/opcache. Does anybody have practical experience?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
Unfortunately a small bug in the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html#tag-aware-adapters).
This  works:

```
cache:
    pools:
        data_evaluator_cache_items_cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
            public: true
        data_evaluator_cache_tags_cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
            public: true

data_evaluator_cache:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter
    arguments:
        $itemsPool: "@data_evaluator_cache_items_cache"
        $tagsPool: "@data_evaluator_cache_tags_cache"
    public: true
```

Comment: To whom it may interest: the apcu cache in these examples really does **not work well**, I personally switched to redis meanwhile.